# How to add entry inside picker popup? Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a picker with more than one hundred data. I want to search a particular item. How can I add a entry inside a picker popup? Is it possible? If not, What are the best alternative to search data inside a picker?

Comment: What are you using for your **Picker**? If it is `Rg.Plugins.Popup`, you can define any elements inside the popup page **you** design. Add an entry to the page and then filter your ObservableCollection<ListItem> by what they type in.

Comment: @TaylorD just a regular picker

Answer (score 0):

What you want might be able to be done via custom renderer, but I personally don't know how that would be done...

If you want custom functionality in a picker, I highly recommend `Rg.Plugins.Popup`. This package allows a user to define there own custom popup. I use this for all my **Popup** pages/controls in the application I develop.

**GitHub:** [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Define a PopupPage with an `Entry` and `ListView` and you can provide the kind of functionality you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for this. But a picker with searchbar can be implemented with **rg.plugins.popup**.(https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).
Create a view with label and down arrow.Provide click for that.In that click event call rg.popup.

The design of popup for referance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="iVerify.Sample"  
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"  
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"  
             BackgroundColor="Transparent" >

    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation   
                      PositionIn="Center"  
                      PositionOut="Center"  
                      ScaleIn="1.2"  
                      ScaleOut="0.8"  
                      DurationIn="400"            
                      DurationOut="300"  
                      EasingIn="SinOut"  
                      EasingOut="SinIn"  
      HasBackgroundAnimation="False"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"  Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,0" >     
     <StackLayout>
         <SearchBar  x:Name="Searchbar" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout>
        <ListView  x:Name="ListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        ItemSelected="List_Tapped">
         ListView.ItemTemplate>

             <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
             <ViewCell.View>

              // Your controls

             </ViewCell.View>
             </ViewCell>
             </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>

      </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

By using Itemselected property you can get the value of tapped view. Then set it to the label of Mainpage(label that clciked to open the popup).This can be achieved by messeging centre.
Sample screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Telerik though it didn't launch on Android in main project for me and the dropdown behaves strange on UWP - it is dropping up instead of down for some layout constellations.

Telerik is not free though, so if you have it you can use:

```
       <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <telerikInput:RadAutoCompleteView x:Name="autoCompleteView"
                                              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                              ShowSuggestionView="True"
                                              ShowMoreItems="True"
                                              SuggestMode="Suggest"
                                              Watermark="Search here..." />
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                            Text="▼"/>
       </StackLayout>
```

and in code behind

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        autoCompleteView.ShowSuggestions();
    }
```